# Can we have Portrait and landscape in same docx report in jsreport

Tags: docx, jsreport

Is it possible to have a docx report with both portrait and landscape in the same report using the recipe: jsreport-html-embedded-in-docx
I tried using jsreport-html-embedded-in-docx-landscape but this overwrites the existing jsreport-html-embedded-in-docx recipe and generates every thing in landscape.

Comment: No we cannot do that